# (CRUD)En el PATRON MVC, los paquetes controller service y repository que funciones cumplen?

Tags: java, mvc, crud

Tengo que hacer un crud, usando el patron MVC, model,view,controller, debo dividir el model en 3 paquetes ,entity, repository y service.

No entendí muy bien la función del paquete controller, service y repository del model.Es un proyecto de practica, no tengo que usar mysql. Repository supongo que seria el emulador de la base de datos.

**En service van los metodos(osea crear,guardar,eliminar,listar)? en repo se guardan los datos y controller maneja las llamadas? es asi?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

- Controller: Irán todas aquellas clases que contengan endpoints. Es decir, llamadas HTTP (GET, POST, DELETE) ... Normalmente anotadas como  @RestController
- Service: Es donde reside la lógica de tu aplicación. Donde pones la mayoría de tu código.
- Repository: Aquí van aquellas clases que se comunican con la BD. Es decir, clases que hacen operaciones en BD.

Un flujo normal sería el siguiente:

Una página(frontend) hace un petición. Tu la captas en los controllers y llamas al service para que te lo atienda y haga el tratamiento necesario.

Según lo que se tenga que hacer se hacen consultas a BD.

Internet -> Controller -> Service -> Repository -> BD